# Auto-Pan/Center/Zoom Map within bounds of JSON markers loaded via .loadURL

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I currently have this bit of code, functioning like I want. I blank out the JSON that is loaded w/ the mapbox map, load one a JSON set from a local file and filter some points out. Was able to figure this out thanks to a previous post.

Now, I'm wanting to auto-pan/zoom the map to encompass only the markers that are visible and having no luck. I've tried several variations of fitBounds and map.extent and feeding it with map.markerLayer.getGeoJSON or markerLayer.getGeoJSON. The former throws a console error of "lat" undefined, which sent me on a console.log hunt and it seems that when you use loadURL, getGeoJSON no longer returns any results?

Thanks for the help. Here's the code.

```
var statestring = String(Request.QueryString("location"));
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'aam.map-ryzdcons');

map.markerLayer.setGeoJSON([]);
var markerLayer = L.mapbox.markerLayer()
.loadURL('markers.geojson.txt')
.setFilter(function(f) {
return f.properties['coverage'].toLowerCase().indexOf(statestring.toLowerCase()) > -1 ; })
.addTo(map);
```

Between here I tried to put map.fitBounds(markerLayer.getBounds()); w/ no success and some other variations.

```
  markerLayer.on('mouseover', function(e) {
      e.layer.openPopup();
  });
  markerLayer.on('mouseout', function(e) {
      e.layer.closePopup();
  });
```

Edit #2: I just tried this, proving my theory that getGeoJSON indeed DOES NOT work when setting loadURL first. It sort of works but doens't accomplish what I want obviously.

```
$.getJSON("markers.geojson.txt", function (data) {
map.markerLayer.setGeoJSON(data);                           
map.fitBounds(markerLayer.getBounds());
if (markers.length == '1') {
map.setZoom(8);
}
map.markerLayer.setGeoJSON([]);
});
```

Edit #3 because it won't let me answer my question for another couple hours:

The answer is: you have to wait for the ready event, at least in my case. Moved the stuff in edit #2 to a markerLayer.on ready event.

```
var markers = [];   
markerLayer.on('ready', function(e) {
this.eachLayer(function(marker) { markers.push(marker); });
map.fitBounds(markerLayer.getBounds());
if (markers.length == '1') {
    map.setZoom(8);
    }
//alert(markers.length);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: you have to wait for the ready event, at least in my case. Moved the stuff in edit #2 to a markerLayer.on ready event.

```
var markers = [];   
markerLayer.on('ready', function(e) {
this.eachLayer(function(marker) { markers.push(marker); });map.fitBounds(markerLayer.getBounds());
if (markers.length == '1') {
map.setZoom(8);
}
//alert(markers.length);
});
```